# number out of string in java

Tags: java, string, numbers

I have something like "ali123hgj". i want to have 123 in integer. how can i make it in java?

Comment: What about `"abc123def567ghi"` or `"abcdef"`?

Comment: You have always 3 chars before the number or it is just an example?

Comment: it is not just three character .it is number between 0 or more character. it can be "123","sdfs","123fdhf","fgdkjhgf123"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following RegExp (see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/):

```
\d+
```

By:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+"); // the regex
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ali123hgj"); // your string

final ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // results

while (matcher.find()) { // for each match
    ints.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group())); // convert to int
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("blah123yeah4yeah".replaceAll("\\D", ""));
// i == 1234
```

Note how this will "merge" digits from different parts of the strings together into one number. If you only have one number anyway, then this still works. If you only want the first number, then you can do something like this:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("x-42x100x".replaceAll("^\\D*?(-?\\d+).*$", "$1"));
// i == -42
```

The regex is a bit more complicated, but it basically replaces the whole string with the first sequence of digits that it contains (with optional minus sign), before using `Integer.parseInt` to parse into integer.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the [Google Guava #CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) Way.

```
String alphanumeric = "12ABC34def";

String digits = CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.retainFrom(alphanumeric); // 1234

String letters = CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER.retainFrom(alphanumeric); // ABCdef
```

> If you only care to match ASCII digits, use

```
String digits = CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9').retainFrom(alphanumeric); // 1234
```

> If you only care to match letters of the Latin alphabet, use

```
String letters = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')
                         .or(inRange('A', 'Z')).retainFrom(alphanumeric); // ABCdef
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it along these lines:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]*([0-9]*)[^0-9]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ali123hgj");
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
if (matchFound) {
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0)));
}
```

It's easily adaptable to multiple number group as well. The code is just for orientation: it hasn't been tested.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
   if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)) {
      index = i; // found a digit
      break;
   }
}
if (index >= 0) {
   int value = String.parseInt(str.substring(index)); // parseInt ignores anything after the number
} else {
   // doesn't contain int...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final List<Integer> scanIntegers2(final String source) {
    final ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    // in real life define this as a static member of the class.
    // defining integers -123, 12 etc as matches.
    final Pattern integerPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\-?\\d+)");
    final Matcher matched = integerPattern.matcher(source);
    while (matched.find()) {
     result.add(Integer.valueOf(matched.group()));
    }
    return result;
```

Input "asg123d ddhd-2222-33sds --- ---222 ss---33dd 234" results in this ouput
[123, -2222, -33, -222, -33, 234]